# Docker - Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_block_size()

Tags: php, docker, mcrypt

In docker I get *Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_block_size()*, in the container I installed php5-mcrypt and in the php.ini I writted extension=mcrypt.so but don't working it.

```
sudo docker exec -i -t docker_pbr_1 /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-mcrypt
php5enmod mcrypt
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I've PHP 5.6 but php5-mcrypt is not found.

Comment: Check you php version `php -v` by this and do `apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt`

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php5.6-mcrypt
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-mcrypt'